# Remove item from multidimensional PHP array and rebase index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array where I need to remove any item where `inTOC is 0 (ie. false`) while keeping the index to be able to loop using `for`.

This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => JAL
            [id] => 798162f0-d779-46b6-96cb-ede246bf4f3f
            [inTOC] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => BRU
                            [id] => 5600b395-4a28-4956-ccbf-9b238c4fa432
                            [inTOC] => 0
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => TEW
                            [id] => 9e2ebbf6-1c81-4ff7-feb5-c5bede2ccd6c
                            [inTOC] => 1
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ABC
            [id] => 761e1909-34b3-4733-aab6-ebef26d3fcb9
            [inTOC] => 1
        )

)
```

This is the function I have so far where I tried `unset` which doesn't rebase and `array_splice` which only removes a child node when the goal is to remove the array:

```
public function tocFilterNonTOC($tree){
      $size = count($tree);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        if ($tree[$i]['inTOC']) {
           $this->tocFilterNonTOC($tree[$i]['children']);
         } else {
           array_splice($tree[$i], $i, 1); // removes the 'name' node (BRU) only
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: So you only want to remove `name` or the entire array that contains `name`?  And why must you be able to use `for` and the int key?  You've heard of `foreach` and many recursive functions?

Comment: @AbraCadaver the entire array and that the array containing `TEW` is index 0

Comment: Got it now.  See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I went back to using `unset` but added `array_values` to the recursive function like so:

```
public function tocFilterNonTOC($tree){
      $size = count($tree);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        if ($tree[$i]['inTOC']) {
           $this->tocFilterNonTOC($tree[$i]['children']);
         } else {
           unset($tree[$i]);
        }
      }
      if ($tree!=null && is_array($tree)) $tree = array_values($tree)
}
```